# Not null columns accepting the NULL values

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with `NOT NULL` columns but when I run the PHP script(Insert query) with `NULL` values, the database inserts a row with `NULL` values. I would like to show the error message when there is no data. I have the following SQLMODE.

`STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`

What could be the problem? Thanks for any input.

```
CREATE TABLE `TABLE1` (
  `aId` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `FirstName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `LastName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `CreateDTM` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`aId`)
)

            $first = $_POST["first"];
            $first = mysql_real_escape_string($first);
            $last = $_POST["last"];
            $last = mysql_real_escape_string($last);

    $insertsql = "INSERT INTO TABLE1(FirstName,LastName) VALUES ('".$first."', '" .$last. "')";
```

Comment: Please show your database structure and the exact code your inserting data. Are you sure you insert a MySQL NULL value and not a simple "NULL" string?

Comment: And where is the NULL value being inserted?

Answer (score 0):

The values are not null, they are empty strings. Those are two completely separate values. Give this a try and it should throw an error:

```
        $first = !empty($_POST["first"])?mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['first']):null;
        $last = !empty($_POST["last"])?mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['last']):null;
```

And it should error out on you. The ? :  are basically a shortened if / else statement called the ternary operator.

The real solution, is not to rely on the database throwing an error, instead, do your check prior to running the query, this way you can handle the error message a bit cleaner and inform the user of what is wrong.

**EDIT**

Why it is inserting, even though set to NULL above?

```
        $insertsql = "INSERT INTO TABLE1(FirstName,LastName) VALUES ('".$first."', '" .$last. "')";
```

Note the single quotes, that would make the value of `$first` taken literally. This is why prepared statements and such are a much better way to do database tasks, as if you remove the single quotes (for testing obviously) my bet is, it would not allow the `null`.

Comment: Still it's inserting the null values.

Comment: Well, you are surrounding the data in the `INSERT` statement by single quotes. This could be making the `NULL` taken literally. As stated, you should implement a better error check system and not rely on MySQL to do it for you. As those values are not truly NULL, since you encase them in single quotes.

Comment: If I remove the single quote, I am getting the following error. "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version"